# Show class on input fields focus within a tr

Tags: jquery

Structure is:

```
<tr>
   <td><span id="smeal-12-12" class="sletindtastningfelt">X</span></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="blabla"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="blabla"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="blabla"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="blabla"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><span id="smeal-13-12" class="sletindtastningfelt">X</span></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="again"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="again"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="again"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="again"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to show class "sletindtastningfelt" if you focus on some of the input fields within the same `tr`

And on blur the class should hide..

And it should use its own class "sletindtastningfelt" and not another tr's class "sletindtastningfelt"

The table id is #diettable

Comment: What do you mean by "use its own class"? All elements in a document must use the same CSS classes.

Comment: Yes but I mean it's own "span class" so the id="" is different as you cansee

Comment: @mblase75: He means he wants to display only the element with class `.sletindtastningfelt` that's in the same `tr` as the `input` focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$('input:text').focus(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.sletindtastningfelt').show();
});
$('input:text').blur(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.sletindtastningfelt').hide();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jP6xM/2/ shows it working -- and I added a line of code to hide them on `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Ok this works how i Want my issue is that when you click on .sletindtastningfelt that has a binded click function, it hides before you click because you go on blur.. What can you do?

Comment: You can attach the methods to the `tr` instead of the `input` -- `$('tr').click(function() { $(this).closest('tr').find('.sletindtastningfelt').show().end().siblings().find('.sletindtastningfelt').hide(); });` -- see http://jsfiddle.net/jP6xM/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('.sletindtastningfelt').hide();

    $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.sletindtastningfelt').show();
    }).blur(function() {
        $('.sletindtastningfelt').hide();
    });
});
```

### [Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/4qtJm/)

Comment: Ok this works too but a new issue appears and it happen when you click on .sletindtastningfelt that has a binded click function, it hides before you click because you go on blur.. What can you do?

Comment: @Karem: You could add a timer to the second `.hide()`. `setTimeout(function() { $('.sletindtastningfelt').hide(); }, 100);` This is not pretty, but [it'll work](http://jsfiddle.net/PE5vX/).